# The context has expired and can no longer be used. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090317)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I had a problem with this error on a site collection and a document wiki library

> The context has expired and can no longer be used. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80090317)

I do reset and removing cache in using [The context has expired and can no longer be used. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090317)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153227/the-context-has-expired-and-can-no-longer-be-used-exception-from-hresult-0x80) and [this](https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701125-Sorry-something-went-wrong-The-context-has-expired-and-can-no-longer-be-used) and reset IIS and SharePoint server and this error still exists.

Comment: You didn't mention trying the 3rd answer of your first link, which suggests reseting the `cache.ini`'s value to `1` while the Timer Service is stopped. Did you try that? If you are about to, first take a copy of the non-modified cache-file to have it as a backup.

Comment: Also, which build of SP2013 do you have running (i.e. what is the latest patch you have installed for your SharePoint)?

Comment: thanks, I did that to and for a while every thing is alright but after that that error happened on wiki library and after that whole site collection !

Comment: @moe maj:15     min:0      build:4569   Rev:1000

Answer (score 4):

I've got two options for you to try out:

The first one is to try this [Ryan McIntyre](http://blog.randomdust.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-claim-expiration-and-ad-sync/)'s suggestion on changing the Security Service's token lifetime which should fix claim expiration. This could fit to your error description as the error appears after some time.

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.FormsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 2)
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 2)
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 1)
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

The second suggestion would be to simply add more RAM to your SharePoint hosting server. You can try with e.g. adding 4 Gb in addition to what you currently have and evaluate the results.